# CSS animation won't play when I add a class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, tailwind-css, jquery-animate

I am trying to add a fadeout transition animation from 100 opacity to 0 opacity for a given div by adding the `animate-fadeout` class to the div, but it's not working. I am using Tailwind CSS, here is my config file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      scale: {
        '65': '0.65',
      },
      // animation class
      animation: {
        fadeout: 'fadeOut 1s ease-in-out',
        fadein: 'fadeIn 1s ease-in-out',
      },
      // actual animation
      keyframes: {
        fadeOut: {
          '0%': { opacity: 100 },
          '100%': { opacity: 0 },
        },
        fadeIn: {
          '0%': { opacity: 0 },
          '100%': { opacity: 100 },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
      <div id="item1" class="carousel-item">
        <img src="images/temp.jpg" class="absolute block w-full">
        <div class="text-shadow-custom pl-72 pr-72 w-full h-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center absolute">
          <p class="text-center text-white text-2xl font-bold">TEST TEXT</p>
          <p class="text-center text-white text-xl">Test description</p>
          <a href="#" class="mt-8 p-2 rounded bg-red-600 text-white">LEARN MORE</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And my javascript is literally just this:

```
$('#item1').addClass('animate-fadeout');
```

But nothing happens. No animation, and the `animate-fadeout` class doesn't even appear in the styles tab in developer tools.

When I put the `animate-fadeout` class directly into the div like this `<div id="item1" class="carousel-item animate-fadeout">` and refresh the page, it works perfectly. I really am lost as to why this isn't working. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Try to make a working example in JSFiddle or Stack Snippet, so we can reproduce.

Comment: I tried JSFiddle, and it's possible to include tailwind.min.css but unfortunately I'm not sure how to include or edit the tailwind.config.js, meaning I can't extend animations to add my own stuff. If you know of a way to do it, I happily will add that.

Tailwind play also doesn't let you add JavaScript, unfortunately

Comment: Your code seems to work as expected [in this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yLd8fkw/). Consider providing code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I added my full code on top of that fiddle... And it works perfectly. I really have no idea what I could be doing wrong. Thanks for the help anyways.